# Jquery code breaks when using replace() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have a simple code that is separating book title from serial using the ":" as separator. This is really a straight forward solution and should work. On my website it's working but stopping when using german umlauts in the book title. So I created a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz1eqzp1/)** to find out what's going on but the code breaks whenever I'm using the `replace()` function.

html:

```
<div id="title">Die Träne des Fressers: Weiße Königin</div>
Title:<div id="output_title">output title</div>
Serial:<div id="output_serial">output serial</div>
```

js:

```
title_input = $("#title").text(); 

title   = title_input.match(/[a-z\s,äöüß-]*.*:/i);
serial  = title_input.match(/:\s?[a-z\s,äöüß-]*/i);

title.replace(/\:/g,'');
//serial = serial.replace(/[:|\.]+/g, "").trim();

$("#output_title").text(title);
$("#output_serial").text(serial);
```

I do not understand what's going on. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: The `.replace()` method returns a new string. It does not change the original string.

Comment: Oh, also, the `.match()` function always returns an **array**, not a string.  The first element of the array (element 0) will contain the matched substring.

Comment: I missed that fact, you're perfectly right and thanks for pointing me out that .match() returns an array - this is new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is returning an array ***not*** a string as you're expecting. You'll need to check for this and select the matching string (if applicable) before calling [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Currently by adding a bit of logging:

```
title_input = $("#title").text(); 

title   = title_input.match(/[a-z\s,äöüß-]*.*:/i);
serial  = title_input.match(/:\s?[a-z\s,äöüß-]*/i);
console.log(title.length); // <-- Logging
```

We can see that `title` is the following:

```
["Die Träne des Fressers:", index: 0, input: "Die Träne des Fressers: Weiße Königin"]
```

For your code to work, you need to get the first element of the `title` array (if available) before calling [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
title_input = $("#title").text(); 

title  = title_input.match(/[a-z\s,äöüß-]*.*:/i);
serial  = title_input.match(/:\s?[a-z\s,äöüß-]*/i);

if(title && title.length) {
  title = title[0];  
  title.replace(/\:/g,'');
}

$("#output_title").text(title);
$("#output_serial").text(serial);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title">Die Träne des Fressers: Weiße Königin</div>
Title:<div id="output_title">output title</div>
Serial:<div id="output_serial">output serial</div>
```

**Extra Note:** To ensure you don't get an `undefined` type error, it's a good idea to ensure that `title` exists and is not an empty array as noted by the `if(title && title.length)` line.

Comment: This is a very good explanation and good example to learn from. Thank you!

Comment: I could also convert the array using String(title) - this should also solve the array problem IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Pointy mentioned in comments the **[match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/match)** return an array and *The first element of the array (element 0) will contain the matched substring* so you have to select first element by addinng `[0]` :

```
title   = title_input.match(/[a-z\s,äöüß-]*.*:/i)[0];
serial  = title_input.match(/:\s?[a-z\s,äöüß-]*/i)[0];
```

Also the **[replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace)** method will return the new string generated after replacement, so you have to assign it to your variable :

```
title = title.replace(/\:/g,'');
```

hope this helps.

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz1eqzp1/1/)**.

Comment: I like the way how you handle the array in this compact notation. You're right I wasn't aware that the return value is an array. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Variable **title** exists only when script can find one of this symbols and title isn't string - it's array. You can't use replace on null or on array.

This should works:

```
var title = $("#title").text(); 
title = title.replace(/[a-z\s,äöüß-]*.*:/i,'');
```

And if you want to split this string you should use .split(':') function.